# Javascript check form field value before submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a search box on my site to search through a database of books. The following options are presented to the user:

- Search Query (a text input field)
- Where to search (a select field with the options: current, archive or all)
- What to search for (a select field with the options: title, author, owner or reader)

As the user types input into the search field suggestions for book titles popup below like Google has when you search. I want to know how to check which option they have chosen search for (i.e. title, author, etc.) and display the suggestions accordingly.

The current code I use is as follows:

#### HTML

```
    <form method='get' action='/main'>
     <label for='search'>Search</label>
     <div style='position:relative;display:inline;'>
      <input type='text' id='search' name='search' onkeyup='showHint(this.value)' autocomplete='off'/>
      <div style='display:inline;' id='txtHint'></div>
     </div>
     <select name='searchIn'>
      <option name='searchIn' id='searchIn' value='current' selected>Current</option>
      <option name='searchIn' id='searchIn' value='archive'>Archive</option>
      <option name='searchIn' id='searchIn' value='all'>All</option>
     </select>
     <select name='searchBy' onChange='getSearchBy(this.value)'>
      <option name='searchBy' id='searchBy' value='Title' selected>By Title</option>
      <option name='searchBy' id='searchBy' value='Author'>By Author</option>
      <option name='searchBy' id='searchBy' value='Owner'>By Owner</option>
      <option name='searchBy' id='searchBy' value='Reader'>By Reader</option>
     </select>
     <input type='submit' class='submit' value='Submit'/>
    </form>
```

#### AJAX/Javascript

```
      function getSearchBy(val){
   return val;
  }
  function showHint(str){
   var xmlhttp;
   if (str.length==0){ 
    document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML='';
    return;
   }
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
   }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
     document.getElementById('txtHint').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
   }
   var searchBy = getSearchBy(document.getElementById('searchBy').value);
   xmlhttp.open('GET','get_hint.php?q='+str+'&searchBy='+searchBy,true);
   xmlhttp.send();
  }
```

The file 'get_hint.php' does all the processing and queries the database and returns the results as the innerHTML of txtHint element...

The getSearchBy function doesn't seem to return 'Author' when the 'By Author' option has been selected, any ideas?

### Update

I know that many of these answers may be right, but I marked the one which arrived quickest right.
Thanks for the quick response from all of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem in this line.

```
document.getElementById('searchBy').value
```

you are searching for an element with id 'searchBy'. but the element name is searchBy not id. So please add an id='searchBy' for the select element. and remove id='searchBy' from options.

```
<select name='searchBy' id='searchBy' onChange='getSearchBy(this.value)'>
      <option  value='Title' selected>By Title</option>
      <option  value='Author'>By Author</option>
      <option  value='Owner'>By Owner</option>
      <option  value='Reader'>By Reader</option>
     </select>
```

Comment: This seems to be working... I will mark it correct when I finish changing the code and it works...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a select/option and want to retrieve the value of the selected option. That's not yet in your js. you Should do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("input[name='searchBy']").value;
```

(not tested yet)

Or more dynamically, on change:

```
$("input[name='searchBy']").change(function(){
if($(this).is(':selected')){ 
///do something
}});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be:
`...is(':selected')...`
?

Comment: Yes it should, sorry, overlooked that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**You have multiple items with the same id attribute in your HTML code.**
If you change the markup to this:

```
<form method='get' action='/main'>
 <label for='search'>Search</label>
 <div style='position:relative;display:inline;'>
  <input type='text' id='search' name='search' autocomplete='off'/>
  <div style='display:inline;' id='txtHint'></div>
 </div>
 <select id='searchIn' name='searchIn'>
  <option value='current' selected>Current</option>
  <option value='archive'>Archive</option>
  <option value='all'>All</option>
 </select>
 <select id='searchBy' name='searchBy'>
  <option value='Title' selected>By Title</option>
  <option value='Author'>By Author</option>
  <option value='Owner'>By Owner</option>
  <option value='Reader'>By Reader</option>
 </select>
 <input type='submit' class='submit' value='Submit'/>
</form>
```

and use jQuery to solve the problem:

```
var searchField = $("#search")
    .on("keyup", function(){
        $.get('get_hint.php', 
            {
                "q": searchField.val(),
                "searchBy": $("#searchBy").val()
            }, 
            function(data){
                $("#txtHint").html(data);
            });     
    });
```

(the question begins with jQuery, so I assume, you already included it, into your project)